# Setting UIImageView in Second UIViewController

Tags: ios5, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I have two `UIViewControllers` in a storyboard (with a `NavigationController`).

I'm accessing the camera and taking a picture in ViewController1.  I want to switch to ViewController2 and display the captured picture in a `UIImageView`.

**ViewController2 H file**

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

{

-IBOutlet UIImageView *matchImage;

}

-(IBAction)restart:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *matchImage;

@end
```

**ViewController1 M file**

After my code to take the picture I attempt to switch views using the following syntax

```
ViewController2 *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

[vc.matchImage setImage:tempImage];
```

The first time I take a picture this works perfectly fine and I see the image in ViewController2.

However I have a back button on ViewController2 with the following syntax

**ViewController2 M** file

```
-(IBAction)restart:(id)sender

{

    ViewController1 *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

This successfully returns to ViewController1 and I'm able to take a picture again and repeat the process.  But after about 3-4 times repeating the process I get Received Memory Warning and the app crashes.  Running the Analyzer in Xcode yields no issues.

If I comment out the following line

```
[vc.matchImage setImage:tempImage];
```

Then I can perform endless captures (over 50 with no issues) but of course ViewController2 does not show an image (it is blank).  So this led me to believe I need to release matchImage (especially because it is a property with a retain attribute).  But this didn't seem to help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm still learning about memory management.

**UPDATE**

Here is a bit more info, after 3 iterations of back and forth switching between the views this is the debugger output.  I put in NSLog statements in the two ViewController viewDidUnload and didReceiveMemoryWarning methods.  So when the Received memory warning occurs it appears 3 "instances" of the 2 viewcontrollers are being unloaded.  So it appears that for each iteration of switching between the viewcontrollers I'm getting a new copy.  Is this what you would expect?

2012-10-22 08:23:32.008 TestApp[787:707] Received memory warning.

2012-10-22 08:23:32.015 TestApp[787:707] viewDidUnload ViewController1: 0xfd52250

2012-10-22 08:23:32.017 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController1: 0xfd52250

2012-10-22 08:23:32.023 TestApp[787:707] viewDidUnload ViewController2

2012-10-22 08:23:32.025 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController2

2012-10-22 08:23:32.028 TestApp[787:707] viewDidUnload ViewController1: 0x16dc30

2012-10-22 08:23:32.030 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController1: 0x16dc30

2012-10-22 08:23:32.033 TestApp[787:707] viewDidUnload ViewController2

2012-10-22 08:23:32.037 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController2

2012-10-22 08:23:32.040 TestApp[787:707] viewDidUnload ViewController1: 0x171de0

2012-10-22 08:23:32.042 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController1: 0x171de0

2012-10-22 08:23:32.044 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController2

2012-10-22 08:23:32.046 TestApp[787:707] didReceiveMemoryWarning ViewController1: 0xfd87580

Comment: Try strong instead of retain and see if that works

Comment: Also try to create one property as `UIImage` and assign `tempImage` to the property and in `viewWillApper:` put `self.matchImage.image = self._your property name_;` may this will work fine :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but the issue still continues.  I've added some of the debugger output to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in your `restart` method is not going back to your previous controller but adding another copy of the first controller type to the navigation stack.  Try telling the navigation controller to `popViewControllerAnimated:` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I overlooked something.  I actually used popToRootViewControllerAnimated: and it is working great.